# Alternative to pull-up resistor

Tags: transistors, pullup, dimensions

I am building this AND gate, and I managed to get it to work properly. However, I had to increase the value of the pull-up resistor to 3 megohms which is too big for what I need. However if I don't make this value big enough, when my input is (0, 0) for example, I won't get an output signal < 0.5 V.

[image: AND Gate design]

How can I ensure that (0,0) (0,1) (1,0) < 0.5V and that (1,1) > 4V. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Um, what transistors?

Comment: Why have you two diodes (DA + DB, etc.) on each input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the forward voltage drop of D11 or D21 when either is low. This follows an exponential curve and is typically 0.6 to 0.7 V at moderate currents.

As you have found, you can reduce the output voltage by limiting the current but at the expense of other characteristics. (You've limited it to something in the order of 1 μA.)

We generally don't use simple diode logic for pure logic circuits although it can be a handy trick when logic gates aren't available or the voltage / power requirement is higher than standard logic gates can handle.

Beware of the tutorials that suggest two NPN transistors in series to create an AND gate. They have several problems.

Answer (score 4):

Why the complication. Just use the standard diode resistor method: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/131860/diode-logic-gates) or maybe [this one](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/diodgate.html): -

[image]

Within reason, this won't have a problem with any value pull-up resistor.

Comment: I am aware of the simpler AND gate, this was an exercise. The exercise gives you that schematic and asks you to analyze what logic gate it represents and then they ask you to modify the values of the circuit so that (1,1) > 4V and all other inputs <0.5V. Sorry I should have clarified in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things you have to take into consideration is if the input will both source and sink current. Is logic low defined as 0 V or the absence of 5 V? That is to say, will whatever drives the gate be able to not only put 5 V on the gate inputs, but also pull them to ground rather than just letting them float.

The voltage sources in LTspice will go to 0 V, which is what you would normally want with diode logic like this. The problem is you have diodes DA, DB,DC and DD connected so that the source will not be able to pull S1 and S2 low.

You can remove those diodes and connect the pulse sources directly to S1 and S2. This will make it so the output can go low. You'll still have the diode drops of D11 and D21 though. You can minimize this by using Schottky diodes. This should reduce the low output voltage to less than 100 mV. You also have to take into account the loading on the output, if R2 is large and loading can reduce your high output voltage significantly. Schottky diodes also have higher reverse leakage than silicon, so you have to adjust the resistances a bit, making the input resistors higher, and the biasing resistor lower.

Here is a simulation showing all of this:
[image: diode and gate]

You can see the output is around 4.6 V for high and 180 mV for low.

**Update:** Thinking about it, you can leave out the 10k resistors. The ones on the input will make little difference except to draw a little more current from the sources, the one on the output will load it down a little, leaving it out gets the logic high voltage close to 5 V.